# Build a Python dictionnary by making a loop through a directory

Tags: python, arrays, loops, dictionary

I have a folder composed of 5 files:

'file42.json', 'file57.json', 'file65.json', 'file81.json', 'file90.json'.

I want to build an dictionary that would look like this :

```
  {
'file42.json' : 42, 
'file97.json' : 57, 
'file57.json' : 65, 
'file81.json' : 81, 
'file90.json' : 90
 }
```

I tried the following snippet ...

```
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
        d = {}
        d[f]=int(f[:-5])
        print d
```

But I get that result, that does not respect how a dictionary should be  :

```
{'file42.json': 10}
{'file57.json': 11}
{'file_65.json': 14}
{'file_81.json': 15}
{'file_90.json': 37}
```

How could I do to build a proper dictionary by using the `for`-loop ?
Thanks !

Comment: move `d = {}` _before_ the loop

Comment: rereading the question, I don't think the result you're getting matches the code you provided. you should get something like `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'file97'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First discover your folder with `os.listdir()`, then strip everything except the number you look for with the `strip()` function:

```
import os

d = {}
for file in os.listdir():
    d[file] = int(file.strip('file').strip('.json'))
print(d)
```

This way you get:

```
 d = {
'file42.json' : 42, 
'file97.json' : 57, 
'file57.json' : 65, 
'file81.json' : 81, 
'file90.json' : 90
 }
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much !! Too bad I kept the d={} inside the loop..

Answer (score 2):

the error is reinitializing the dict in the loop. Printing each occurrence makes it look like you're *building* a dictionary, but actually you aren't.

After that, your slicing is incorrect: you have to remove the extension and the prefix, so simple slicing won't cut it either, so the results you're getting *cannot* be from the code you're trying to run.

The best way to do this is through dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> import glob
>>> import os
>>> d = {k: int(os.path.splitext(k)[0][-2:]) for k in globi.glob("*.json")}
>>> d
{'file97.json': 97, 'file42.json': 42}
```

For the value, extract the non-extension part, take the 2 numbers and convert.

This doesn't work if there is one or 3 digits, so regular expression is probably a better choice:

```
>>> import re
>>> d = {k: int(re.search("\d+", os.path.splitext(k)[0]).group(0)) for k in glob.iglob("*.json")}
```

Comment: `glob.iglob` is preferred I would say, especially in a comprehension.

Comment: Thank you very much for the two methods, that's great it works well !